# Roblox Lua: Issue defining a value in a player's leaderstats folder (no error message)

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a system in my game where when a player steps on a checkpoint, a `Stage` value in the leaderboard will go up, and then that value is saved to that player's `userId`.

I want there to be a `button` that resets that value back to `0`, and this is the code I tried for it.

```lua
    local textButton = script.Parent
    local Players = game:GetService("Players")

    textButton.MouseButton1Up:Connect(function()
         local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
         local stage = Players:WaitForChild(player):WaitForChild("leaderstats").Stage
         if stage.Value > 1 then
              stage.Value = 1
         end
    end)
```

I've tried debugging it by putting print commands in different places to see where the code gets, and when I try to run print(`stage`) it does not show anything.

Comment: Is this a Script or a LocalScript? And where is it located?

Comment: this is a localscript inside the TextButton in a screengui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LocalScripts` cannot change the value on the server. To change a value once a button is clicked, `RemoteEvents` should be used.
There is a page documenting about them here: https://create.roblox.com/docs/scripting/networking/remote-events-and-functions
To use a `RemoteEvent`, first you need to put it in a place that is replicated across the server and the client. A good example of this would be to put it in `ReplicatedStorage`. After that, you need to set up a script that listens for the `.OnServerEvent` event of the `RemoteEvent`. To do this, you need to connect a function. As seen in your script, you already know how to do this. So I will get straight to the point.
On the server, set up a script that listens for `.OnServerEvent`. Next, on the client, edit your script to fire the client instead of trying to set the value. Go back to the server script, and set the value there. The event also passes the `Player` object, so you can utilize that to actually reset the value.

TLDR;
`LocalScript` inside of your `TextButton`:

```
local textButton = script.Parent
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local RemoteEvent = 'RemoteEvent location'

textButton.MouseButton1Up:Connect(function()
    RemoteEvent:FireServer()
end)
```

Server `Script` in anywhere, preferably `ServerScriptService`:

```
RemoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
    local Players = game:GetService("Players")
    local stage = Players:WaitForChild(player):WaitForChild("leaderstats").Stage
    if stage.Value > 1 then
        stage.Value = 1
    end
end)
```

Good luck!